# How to get the current fixed position in emulator?

Tags: android

I'm trying an application that displays the latitude and longitude positions. I tried giving lat. & lon. values using geo fix and even emulator control but I'm not getting the output. Can anyone help me out?

Here's the code and output that i get:

```
public class LocationTest extends Activity
{
    private LocationManager mgr;
    private TextView output;
    private String best;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Enabled Provider:");

        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String provider = mgr.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        mgr.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0,
        new LocationListener()
        {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        });
        sb.append("\n").append(provider).append(":");
        Location location = mgr.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        if (location != null)
        {
            double lat = location.getLatitude();
            double lng = location.getLongitude();
            sb.append(lat).append(",").append(lng);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.append("No Location");
        }
        output.setText(sb);
    }
}
```

Output:

Enabled provider:
gps:No Location

Answer (score 0):

You need to put code in `public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {}` of your `LocationListener`. This is where location changes are informed.

`getLastKnownLocation()` doesn't give you current location, but **last known location** (which will most likely be *null* on the emulator).

Use Android SDK's DDMS to signal GPS position. This will call `onLocationChanged()`. You need a way to preserve the new location in your class (for example adding a `Location` class object to your `Activity`).

Comment: I'm not changing my location. i jus need to get the value that I'm feeding. Then what's the need to put the code in onLocationChanged(Location location)? It should work properly right?

Comment: Doesn't matter. First location event is sent to *onLocationChanged()*. As I said, the getLastKnownLocation can be null, while the onLocationChanged() provides a valid Location object.

Comment: As you said i tried putting the code in onLocationChanged() but even then the application is not displaying the coordinates.

Comment: That will only work if Location changes (this also means the first Location event is a Location change). If Location never changes (that is, if you never get a Location event), it's useless to get a Location. If there's no new Location event, that method will never be called. Try to set a new Location using DDMS as I said on the answer. And also, can you post what code you put there?